# PopUp menu will not center horizontal

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I instantiate a popup menu in Xamarin studio / C# in this way:

```
PopupMenu puMenu = new PopupMenu(myActivity, view, GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal);
```

With this I expect the puMenu to center horizontal, but this is not the case. The puMenu continues to be left aligned.

If i replace "CenterHorzontal" with "Right" like this:

```
PopupMenu puMenu = new PopupMenu(myActivity, view, GravityFlags.Right);
```

the puMenu is right aligned as I expect.

Any clues to whats wrong with the first statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

PopupWindow puMenu = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate    (R.layout.popup_example, null, false),100,100, true);
puMenu.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Using PopupWindow could be an alternative, but it do not automatically anchor to the listViewItem, so I had preferere if the gravity parameter in the popupMenu construkter behaved as I would expect.